# Help with an integral given an integral

Tags: calculus

Im having trouble with integrals so far, I'm getting standard "evaluate this integral" but not this question.

**QUESTION:**
Given that $\int_{-5}^3f(x)dx=5$, evaluate $\int_{-5}^3 \left(2f(x)-3\right)dx$

How do I get started with this and what are some good recourses to review, I feel as if I missed something simple and haven't been able to figure it out...
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

How do you get started? First step would be to make sure you understand the concept of integration(and then proceed along), rather than mugging up formulae. Second step would be to not over-complicate the problem statement.

Given: $$\int_{-5}^3f(x)dx=5$$
Evaluate:
$$\int_{-5}^3 \left(2f(x)-3\right)dx$$
$$=\int_{-5}^3 2f(x)dx-\int_{-5}^3 3dx$$
$$=2\int_{-5}^3 f(x)dx-\int_{-5}^3 3dx$$
Hope you can proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

$\int 2f(x)dx=2\int f(x)dx=10$ and $\int 3dx=3\int dx=24$  Net result $-14$.